# Работа с БД Android

Tags: android, sqlite

Работаю в Android Studio. Прочитал в [гайде](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/database.php) про базу данных, но научился только получать из нее данные с помощью `Cursor` и вставлять данные с помощью `insert()` 
А вот недавно возникла проблема. Я пытаюсь вставить в БД имя активити и при следующем запуске вывести его, но почему-то не получается.

```
Cursor cursor = mSqLiteDatabase.query(
            "pts", new String[]{
                    DatabaseHelper.ACHIVE_NAME
            },
            null, null, null, null, null
    );

    cursor.moveToLast();

    String testValue = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.ACHIVE_NAME));

    Boolean isEmpty = false;
        if (testValue == null) {
            isEmpty = true;
        }
        else if (testValue.isEmpty()) {
            isEmpty = true;
        }
    if (isEmpty) {
        //Вызываем окно для ввода имени
        showNameDialog(mSqLiteDatabase);
    }
    else {

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(testValue);

    }
```

Получается вот что - вылезает окошко, я ввожу имя активити, на тулбаре оно высвечивается, все пока хорошо. Но при повторном открытии активити заново появляется это окно, на тулбаре - стандартная надпись( Думаю, что проблема в `moveToLast()`, может надо `moveToFirst()`. Я пробовал, но не получилось( Короче, понятно, что тут что-то с базой данных. Я с ней плохо еще работаю, так что помогите пожалуйста)

P.s. Что выполняется в showNameDialog после нажатия на "Готово" -

```
EditText pointName = (EditText) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.pointName);
                    pointText = pointName.getText().toString();

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    // Задайте значения для каждого столбца
                    values.put(DatabaseHelper.ACHIVE_NAME, pointText);
                    // Вставляем данные в таблицу
                    //mSqLiteDatabase.
                    mSqLiteDatabase.insert("pts", null, values);

                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(pointText);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `moveToLast()` курсора устанавливает положение курсора на самую последнюю позицию в БД. Например, если в поле activity будет находиться два значения: MainActivity и TwoActivity. При использовании `moveToLast()` в выборке вы будете получать каждый самое последние значение, т. е. в нашем случае -TwoActivity. При использовании `moveToFirst()` - всегда самое первое значение. Вам же в теле цикла нужно перебрать все возможные значения, удовлетворяющие какому-то условию с помощью метода курсора `moveToNext()`. Пример чтобы проще было понять о чём я:

```
 // делаем выборку по названию категории и города из столбца columns
 Cursor cursor = sqdb.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
     columns
 }, CATEGORY + " = ? OR " + CITY + " = ?", new String[] {
     categories,
     city
 }, null, null, null);
 // проверяем существуют ли данные удовлетворяющие нашему условию
 if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
     // перебираем все значения и добавляем их в коллекцию
     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
         array.add(cursor.getString(0));
     }
 }
```